# Load images from assets folder ( error loading *.png )

Tags: android, bitmap

I wrote the code loader images from assets folder following the example [code](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

[my code](http://wklej.to/5HKc1)

I don't know why load *.png not work. JPG work.

JPG work

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeStreamFromAssets("test.jpg", 64, 64);
    if(bitmap != null){

        imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {

        Logs.e("error");
    }
```

PNG not work ( is error )

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeStreamFromAssets("test.png", 64, 64);
    if(bitmap != null){

        imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {

        Logs.e("error");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways by which you can load image from assets folder.

**Solution 1:**

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test, null);  
 imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
 InputStream ins = null; 

 try {  
      ins = getAssets().open("test.png");   
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);  
      imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (final IOException e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();  
 } finally {  
      if (ins != null)  
   try {  
      ins.close();  
   } catch (IOException e) { }  
 }
```

I suggest to use second one because good performance.

Running both functions 50 times to load a small PNG file (230*230) on Nexus

Galaxy running Android 4.2.2:

**decodeResource: 1793ms**

**decodeStream: 188ms**

Comment: Yes, it work, but i would load scaled large bitmap for ex. test.png have 2056x2056 i want load 128x128. ( optimalization memory ) as in link number 1. The problem is that when i try load PNG file it not work, but JPG load normally.

Answer (score 0):

where the decodeStreamFromAssets?

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

it work!